# g++ on Mac OS X - CoreServices.h Error

Tags: c++, macos, g++, core-services

When I compile the following code with `g++`

```
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error.

```
bash-3.2$ g++ test.C
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:0,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:20,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:21,
                 from test.C:1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBundle.h:147:120: error: format string argument not a string type
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get it to work?  I am trying to use `mach_absolute_time` and `AbsoluteToNanoseconds`, which is in `CoreServices.h`, like [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html).

```
g++ -v
gcc version 4.5.0 20100107 (experimental) (GCC)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use Apple's frameworks without using Apple's toolchain - that's probably not going to work.  Your example program compiles fine here for me, using the gcc that came with Xcode (and with clang):

```
$ cat example.cpp 
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  return 0;
}
$ make example
g++     example.cpp   -o example
$ rm example
$ CXX=clang make example
clang     example.cpp   -o example
$
```

Comment: Carl, gcc 4.5 is definitely not Apple. They gave up GCC since the project changed the license and are being focused on Clang/LLVM, not doing any major releases of the compiler yet.

Comment: @Vlad - that's what I said in my answer, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong. You just said "it looks like", and I am  confirming that it is exactly what it looks like :-)

Comment: Apple's changes to gcc are public, though, so you could still pester the gcc guys to merge them.